# asp.net - Reading Excel Sheet Names Not Returning Data Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

You might redirect me to other links for this one, but I'll be the first to tell you guys: I'VE USED THIS FOR MANY TIMES and I really don't know what's the problem this time.

My scenario is: I need to import Excel data into the database. Sounds easy, right? Now, first I need to know the sheet names. That's where my problem started. And I repeat, I've used it for multiple times, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong this time:

The 'it' I'm referring to is this piece of code:

```
public string[] GetSheetNames(string excelPath) {

            try
            {

            string[] ar = null;

            if (Path.GetExtension(excelPath) == ".xls")
            {
                conString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + excelPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"");
            }

            else if (Path.GetExtension(excelPath) == ".xlsx")
            {
                conString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";");
            }

                using (oleConn = new OleDbConnection(conString))
                {
                    oleConn.Open();

                    if (oleConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {

                        //DataTable dt = oleConn.GetSchema("Tables");

                        //DataTable dt = oleConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new Object[] {null, null, null, "TABLE"});

                        DataTable dt = oleConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

                        if (dt == null)
                        {
                            return null;
                        }

                        ar = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
                        int t = 0;

                        foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows){

                            ar[t] = dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                            t++;
                        }


                    }


                    return ar;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

It throws an Exception, saying that the DataTable's row count is 0. I also used `DataTable dt = oleConn.GetSchema("Tables")` and

```
DataTable dt = oleConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, 
          new Object[] {null, null, null, "TABLE"});
```

but they all returned the same.

What could be the problem? Could it be the Excel file? But I've tried other Excel files and they all failed.

Comment: Can you post debug visualizer of `DataTable dt`?

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
  OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'");
  connection.Open();
  DataTable Sheets = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

  foreach (DataRow dr in Sheets.Rows)
  {
     string sht = dr[2].ToString().Replace("'", "");
     OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sht + "]", connection);
  }
```

Comment: bro, i need to get the sheet names, not to query in a particular sheet.

Comment: can't even enter my foreach loop because the row count is 0.

Comment: i checked this code and it's work, check your excel load file

Comment: It helps to provide an explanation of your answer rather than just a code dump.

Comment: i trace your code and  checked with .xls and .xlsx file. it's work correctly.

Comment: @asieh - i'm certain you're sure it works, but compare it to my code, it's almost the same. and i can tell you it really can't reach the loop.

Comment: i write a WindowsFormsApplication for test your code do you want to send you this app?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need options but this just happened to me and I got a solution.

My problem was the file itself, when copying to local folder I didn't add the extension so when the connection opens it creates an empty file with no sheets (that's no tables to read)

If you are moving your file to a local folder, take a look into the file and see if it's not corrupted and it does has something to read after the copy.

Comment: That is one of the possible reasons for this error. The file path or file name might be wrong. Maybe that can help someone.

Answer (score -1):

```
private DataSet GetExcelWorkSheet(string pathName, string fileName, int workSheetNumber)
{
    OleDbConnection ExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + @"\" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
    OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand();
    ExcelCommand.Connection = ExcelConnection;
    OleDbDataAdapter ExcelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ExcelCommand);

    ExcelConnection.Open();
    DataTable ExcelSheets = ExcelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
    string SpreadSheetName = "[" + ExcelSheets.Rows[workSheetNumber]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "]";

    DataSet ExcelDataSet = new DataSet();
    ExcelCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM " + SpreadSheetName;

    ExcelAdapter.Fill(ExcelDataSet);

    ExcelConnection.Close();
    return ExcelDataSet;
}
```

Comment: It helps to provide an explanation of your answer rather than just a code dump.